# Display Japanese characters through web service response

Tags: web-services, rest, localization

We are using REST web services in our application some of my response has string in japanese language which gets rendered as wiered Boxes on the page. Can someone please help me on this.

Appreciate the help in advance.

Vaibhav Goswami.

Comment: What is the content-type of the response?

Comment: It is UTF-8,  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> We are getting a response from an external service fom httpclient and then loosing its values into boxes..

Comment: Are you sure that the response content itself is correctly encoded? Have you tried to connect to web service "manually"? What technology are you using both for back end and the client (HttpClient seems like .Net)? I do not seem to understand "loosing its values into boxes"...

Answer (score 2):

I guess there are a few possibilities here (that I can think of):

#### 1. Content-Type is not set correctly

Although your XML document contains the correct value, it's possible that the responses `Content-Type` header does not have the correct charset value. Can you check this value? It should contain something like:

`text/html;charset=utf-8`

#### 2. The application you're using to view the response data does not support unicode

Are you sure the data in the response is incorrect? Do you have an editor or viewing that you are certain supports unicode that you can try? If the application you're using to view the response data can't handle unicode, it may be showing you the boxes even though the response data is fine.

#### 3. The characters are not UTf-8 encoded

How is this XML content being produced and how is it written into the response? Is it possible that the header is incorrectly reporting the content as UTF-8 when the characters being inserted are actually some other encoding, like UTF-16?

#### Other thoughts...

You mention that the errors look incorrect when rendered 'on the page'. What exactly do you mean by this? Is this XML being used to generate some HTML on the server before being shown in the browser? It's possible that your XML response is UTF-8 encoded, but the HTML is served up with the wrong charset information.